# Xpath How to check if a child element exist given the parent node?

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I wanted to loop over the parent node and check if a parent node has a certain child and extract data from it.

The script of the website is something like this:

```
<div @class="reviews">
  <div @id = "user1">
    <div @class="name"> Will </div>
    <div @class="weight"> 50kg </div>
    <div @class="height"> 160cm </div>
  </div>
  <div @id = "user2">
    <div @class="weight"> 55kg </div>
    <div @class="height"> 170cm </div>
  </div>
  <div @id = "user3">
    <div @class="name"> Ben </div>
    <div @class="height"> 180cm </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My code so far looks something like this:

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get( 'url of a website')

name_row = []
weight_row = []
height_row = []
for i in range(len(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="reviews"/div'):
    # Get the first parent (user1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="reviews"/div)' + '[' + str(i + 1) + ']')
    
    # Check if it has elements like name, weight, and height and add it to appropriate list. 
    # For example, name_row.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to name if it exists")
    # If missing any element return "None"
    # Then move on to the second parent (user2) and so on

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': name_row, 'Weight': weight_row, 'Height': height_row})
```

I want my end result to look like

| Name | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Will | 50kg | 160cm |
| None | 55kg | 170cm |
| Ben | None | 180cm |

I've looked at other posts too but just can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

I tried just doing find_elements_by_xpath and put each name, weight, and height values in their respective list but this would not include the "None" value in any of these list and end up giving me error of array not being the same length and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get( 'url of a website')

names = []
weights = []
heights = []
#wait for first parent element to be visible
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='reviews']")))
#let all the elements loaded
time.sleep(0.5)
#get all the reviews list
reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='reviews']")
#iterate over reviews and get each inner element per each review
for i in range(len(reviews)):
    #get name element for current review. This returns list of web elements
    name = review[i].find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='name']")
    #in case the element exists the list is non-empty so it is interpreted as Boolean True
    if(name):
        #extract actual element value and append it to the list of names
        names.append(name[0].text)
    #otherwise append "None"
    else:
        names.append("None")
    #the same for other parameters
    weight = review[i].find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='weight']")
    if(weight):
        weights.append(weight[0].text)
    else:
        weights.append("None")
    height = review[i].find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='height']")
    if(height):
        heights.append(height[0].text)
    else:
        heights.append("None")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you got the parents element, you can now again for the child element inside parent element like for you

```
parents=driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="reviews"/div).find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
```

For do loop using parent elements, and check inside that if other exist or not.

```
for parent in parents:
    parent.find_element_by_class_name('name')
    ....weight 
    Height
```

[Here's](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name) documentation

> Use this when you want to locate an element by class name. With this strategy, the first element with the matching class name attribute will be returned. If no element has a matching class name attribute, a NoSuchElementException will be raised.

So, now you can do `try` `except` while checking for name, weight.. and if found get data if not write None